# how to give optional install for multiple msi packages in single WiX installer?

Tags: visual-studio, wix, windows-installer, desktop-application, wix3.11

I have multiple packages that I want to install using single installer. Two of them are MSI packages, other two are exe files. I am using WiX to make single installer to install all four packages, and want to give user option to choose which one (or more) they want to install.

Here, One MSI package is for WPF Desktop application that I am developing, other 3 packages are add-on features that I want to give option to select/deselect.

So, far I am able to install all four of them using WiX BootStrapper. But I could not find how to give select options to user during installation.

Also I am using Visual Studio 2019 IDE for development.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your using the standard bootstrapper application you need to bring in a copy of your favorite Theme.wxl:

```
<BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.HyperlinkLicense" >
  <bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication LicenseFile="Resources\EULA.rtf" LogoFile="Resources\Icon.png" LicenseUrl="http://www.google.com" LocalizationFile="Resources\HyperlinkTheme.wxl" ThemeFile="Resources\HyperlinkTheme.xml" SuppressOptionsUI="yes" />
</BootstrapperApplicationRef>
```

Then in the Theme wxs add a button:

```
 <Text X="11" Y="175" Width="130" Height="20" FontId="3" Visible="yes" DisablePrefix="yes">Install Something</Text>
 <Checkbox Name="INSTALLSOMETHING"  X="140" Y="175" Width="-11" Height="20" TabStop="yes" FontId="3" Visible="yes"></Checkbox>
```

Then in your bundle.wxs declare a variable so it can be passed as an argument for silent installations:

```
 <Variable Name="INSTALLSOMETHING" bal:Overridable="yes" Type="string" Value="" />
```

And finally use it's value to control the installation of something.

```
   <ExePackage Id="Something" SourceFile="Something.exe" InstallCondition="(INSTALLSOMETHING=&quot;1&quot;) or (INSTALLSOMETHING=&quot;True&quot;)" />
```

Rinse and repeat 3 more times.

Comment: do you know how to do this with BootstrapperApplication inside a c# application? Binding a checkbox with bootdtrapper Variable?